# O que é Flyway e quando usá-lo?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, versionamento

O sistema recentemente chamou atenção para [esta questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146096/64969), e nela se fala sobre Flyway.

Então, gostaria de saber:

- o que é Flyway?
- quais problemas ele se propõe a sanar?
- quando usá-lo?
- quais são as soluções concorrentes?
- ele serve para multi-tenancy? se sim, para bancos de esquema heterogêneos, serve também?

Comment: Algumas das perguntas estão respondidas em https://flywaydb.org

Comment: @Dherik, de fato essa é a referência canônica. Mas como não se tem aqui no SOpt a resposta canônica, senti a necessidade de realizar essa pergunta

Comment: Texto interessante relacionado: [Evolutionary Database Design](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/evodb.html) (Flyway é citado no final)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> o que é Flyway?

Flyway é uma dentre as várias ferramentas que se propõem a trazer ordem e organização para os scripts SQL que são executados no banco de dados, funcionando como um controle de versão do mesmo.

> quais problemas ele se propõe a sanar?

Uma ferramenta como esta permite:

- Sincronizar o banco de dados com a versão da aplicação;
- Saber quais scripts SQL foram executados ou não;
- Automatizar a execução dos scripts;
- Criar um banco de dados do zero;
- Permite criar um rollback de mudanças no banco de dados (útil em casos raros).

> quando usá-lo?

Creio que é uma opção válida para projetos de qualquer tamanho. Como elas costumam ser ferramentas de fácil configuração e uso, não vejo muitos motivos para abrir mão dela, pois ela traz consigo várias vantagens.

Ela pode ser dispensável em alguns projetos onde existam DBAs envolvidos e estes preferem controlar os scripts SQL aplicados fora da aplicação.

> quais são as soluções concorrentes?

O Flyway é uma ferramenta voltada ao ecossistema do Java. Há outras alternativas que também funcionam com Java mas são independentes da linguagem, como o [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org), que traz algumas características a mais bem [interessantes](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/xml_format.html).

No ecossistema do C# já tive a oportunidade de usar com sucesso o [FluentMigrator](https://fluentmigrator.github.io). Atualmente, este tipo de ferramenta é bem comum e cada ecossistema fornece alguma alternativa.

> ele serve para multi-tenancy? se sim, para bancos de esquema heterogêneos, serve também?

Sim, para as [duas perguntas](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq#multiple-schemas).

Se os schemas forem idênticos e existir uma por *tenant*, basta você iterar por cada schema existente e rodar o Flyway em cada um. Se todos terem schemas idênticos, haverá uma única tabela de histórico que ficará no primeiro schema da lista dentre os schemas suportados.

Se os schemas de cada *tenant* forem diferentes, mesmo que com ciclos de vida distintos, você ainda assim pode usar o Flyway para controlá-los, mantendo múltiplas instâncias do Flyway e permitindo que cada instância gerencie seu schema e seu histórico.