# Como adicionar registro na lista sem prejudicar os dados existentes

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

Boa tarde pessoal,

Eu tenho uma model chamada Usuario que tem uma lista de permissão, exemplo:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
private String nome;

@NotNull
private String email;

@NotNull
private String senha;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "usuario_permissao", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id"), 
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permissao_id"))
private Set<Permissao> permissoes;
```

Ao iniciar o projeto, um SQL é rodado populando algumas tabelas, inclusive o usuário com as suas permissões.

Minha dúvida é, como faço para adicionar novas permissões na tabela Usuario sem excluir os dados que já estão na lista de permissões, no momento eu passo um json com apenas 1 nova permissão e com isso ele substitui o que já tem na lista.

UsuarioService

```
public Usuario updateAcess(Long id, Usuario usuario) {
    Usuario usuarioSalvo = findById(id);

    BeanUtils.copyProperties(usuario, usuarioSalvo, "id", "nome", "email", "senha");

    return usuarioRepository.save(usuarioSalvo);
}
```

UsuarioResource

```
@PutMapping("/acesso/{id}")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USUARIO_ATUALIZAR') and #oauth2.hasScope('write')")
public ResponseEntity<Usuario> updateAcess(@PathVariable Long id, @Valid @RequestBody Usuario usuario) {
    Usuario usuarioSalvo = usuarioService.updateAcess(id, usuario);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(usuarioSalvo);
}
```

JSON Antigo

```
{
"id": 2,
"nome": "Usuario",
"email": "email",
"senha": "senha",
"permissoes": [
    {
        "id": 7,
        "descricao": "ROLE_DESPESA_DELETAR"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "descricao": "ROLE_CONTARECEBER_CRIAR"
    }
]}
```

JSON Novo

```
{
"id": 2,
"nome": "Usuario",
"email": "email",
"senha": "senha",
"permissoes": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "descricao": "ROLE_RECEITA_DELETAR"
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom, esse é um problema de organização muito comum em projeto. É criado uma versão inicial do banco, mas por alguma razão foi necessário alterar a estrutura ou até mesmo ampliar e adicionar novas tabelas, para este tipo de problema podemos usar o [FlyWay](https://flywaydb.org/). O uso dele é extremamente simples de entender e fácil de usar.

---

### O que é Flyway?

> Flyway é uma dentre as várias ferramentas que se propõem a trazer
>   ordem e organização para os scripts SQL que são executados no banco de
>   dados, funcionando como um controle de versão do mesmo.

Fonte: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/332547/20508

Comment: Estou usando o Flyway mesmo para a criação das tabelas.

Comment: Então é só criar um novo script para a inserção das novas permissões

Comment: Na pergunta vc não citou estar usando o flyway, nem outro versionamento

Comment: Mais eu quero fazer essa inserção pelo front end, mais estou testando no Postman, passando um Json, com as informações do usuário e com uma permissão na lista, com isso, ele apaga as permissões antigas.

Comment: neste link tem orientação do versionamento https://javabeginnerstutorial.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-flyway-example/

Comment: Entendi, então o relacionamento esta incorreto

Comment: O problema esta aqui, cascade = CascadeType.ALL

Comment: Vc persiste as permissões para o usuário, o cascade.ALL adiciona todas persistencia e prende ela a entidade pai, sugiro que vc altere o cascade para = cascade.PERSIST . Assim ele vai somente cadastrar novas permissões caso ela não exista no banco

Comment: Ainda não deu certo, vou editar a pergunta com o resultado.

Comment: Tente usar mais de um cascade com o que vc realmente vai usar, pois o Cascade.ALL inclui o Cascade.REMOVE, que, se vc retirar uma permissão, ele vai deletar ela

Comment: Todos estão removendo o antigo e adicionando na lista apenas o novo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101479/discussion-between-weslley-barbosa-and-murylo-capcuho).